# How to get all values from List of Map in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, hashmap

I have list of Map.

```
List(Map(term_id -> 20898477-2374-4d4c-9af0-8ed9c9829c94), 
Map(term_id -> 6d949993-1593-4491-beae-eb9bf8abcf27), 
Map(term_id -> 1123c413-3ffd-45ed-8215-dd1bccb3a48f))
```

and want to get all value and check if a term_id already exist in above list of Map.

This can be done with iterating list and checking value of each map. But I  want something more efficient and one liner. I am okay with either of Java or Scala approach.

This question may be naive, but I am not getting at how to proceed. I am new to Java/Scala.

**Expected Output:**

```
List(20898477-2374-4d4c-9af0-8ed9c9829c94, 6d949993-1593-4491-beae-eb9bf8abcf27,
123c413-3ffd-45ed-8215-dd1bccb3a48f)
```

Comment: iterating through each element is indeed the most efficient way if this same data structure is used

Comment: @StinePike, is it possible to unpack list of map and find any Map which contains an `element` as value without iterating?

Comment: What are in your Maps ?   It looks like each one only contains a single entry.

Comment: Yes, key is same for each Map in List of Map and each Map contain single entry.

Comment: can you please list final output what you want?

Comment: Who deleted one answer? That was also another approach to get expected output. If you read this comment please put that answer back. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think flatMap is what you want:

```
val maplist=List(Map("term_id" -> "20898477-2374-4d4c-9af0-8ed9c9829c94"), Map("term_id" -> "6d949993-1593-4491-beae-eb9bf8abcf27"), Map("term_id" -> "1123c413-3ffd-45ed-8215-dd1bccb3a48f"))

maplist.flatMap(_.values)
//res0: List[String] = List(20898477-2374-4d4c-9af0-8ed9c9829c94, 6d949993-1593-4491-beae-eb9bf8abcf27, 1123c413-3ffd-45ed-8215-dd1bccb3a48f)

maplist.flatMap(_.keys)
//res1: List[String] = List(term_id, term_id, term_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use below code to get list of values

```
   val maplist=List(Map("term_id" -> "20898477-2374-4d4c-9af0-8ed9c9829c94"), Map("term_id" -> "6d949993-1593-4491-beae-eb9bf8abcf27"), Map("term_id" -> "1123c413-3ffd-45ed-8215-dd1bccb3a48f"))

    maplist.map(x=>x.get("term_id")
```

Output:

```
List[Option[String]] = List(Some(20898477-2374-4d4c-9af0-8ed9c9829c94), Some(6d949993-1593-4491-beae-eb9bf8abcf27), Some(1123c413-3ffd-45ed-8215-dd1bccb3a48f))
```